# Add a white background to a .png UIImage file with HSImageSidebarView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimage

How can I add a white background to a .png `UIImage` file with [HSImageSidebarView](https://github.com/bjhomer/HSImageSidebarView)?

I have tried creating a `UIImageView` then showing that on the sidebar, but unfortunately the app crashes with an NSException. Any ideas on how to add a white background to the image files on the sidebar if they are a `UIImage` instead of a `UIImageView`.

Comment: I check that fot that u should use scroll view and create view in them in different different position if you want i write one code you try for that

Comment: If this answer is helpful for you please inform us so this will be helpful for others.

Comment: Its working for me I dont know why its not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You will try this code add one scrollview on nib and set its contentsize on viewdidload

```
CGFloat x = 20;
for (int i = 0;i<[playerScores count];i++) {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 10, 60, 60)];
    view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:[playerScores objectAtIndex:i]];
    [view setText:text];

    [yardsScrollView addSubview:view];
    [myLabel release];
    x = x+125;
}
```

PlayersScore is a NSMutable array which have many text like how much view You want.

Answer (score 0):

@objc-obsessive

```
You will need to loop through the subviews to find whether it is of kind UIImage or UIImageView by this:
id object; 
if([object isKindOfClass:[UIImage Class]]) {
     //Do whatever u want to here by creating a new imageView on the top of this image
     //Something like this:
UIImage *image =(UIImage*)object;
UIImageView *imgView=[[uiimageview alloc]initwithimage:image];

//Now perform the background view operations on imgView i.e. instance of UIImageView.
}

//Hope it works.
```